# NEXT JS - MongoDB| 500: Internal Server Error after Deployment on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, vercel

This is my first **Next JS - MongoDB** Project, so everything works fine on my localhost. After I deployed my website on Vercel, I got  **500: Internal Server Error** on several routes (I think it's only the ones that have their data filled from the database), I double-checked my **environment variables** and everything was fine so I'm guessing this error has to do with "**getServerSideProps**", I've seen similar questions online. Still, I didn't find any helpful solutions.

Here's my code on GitHub: https://github.com/MoeElItani/Click-N-Eat
and my deployed website: https://click-n-eat.vercel.app/

On Localhost:
[image: On Localhost]

Deployed:
[image: Deployed]

Comment: What error do you see in Vercel's [Function Logs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs)?

Comment: Kudos to you I didn't notice the function log even existed, after I saw the logs I noticed my mistake, I was getting my data from localhost:3000/api/Items in the serverless function.. fixed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)
I checked my [Function Logs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs) and I found out the problem was that I was getting my data from **localhost:3000/api/...**

```
  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/Items/${params.id}`);
```

Changed to:

```
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/Items/${params.id}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mongodb atlas cluster, whitelist your ip. Change to 0.0.0.0. This will allow access database from anywhere.